# Why is my docker command from ant not executed?

Tags: ant, docker

I have a simple docker command

```
$ docker rm 1234
> Error response from daemon: No such container: 1234
```

Integration this into ant gives:

```
<target name="demo">
    <exec executable="docker">
        <arg value="rm 1234" />
    </exec>
</target>

> ant -v demo
> demo:
     [exec] Current OS is Linux
     [exec] Executing 'docker' with arguments:
     [exec] 'rm 1234'
     [exec] 
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
     [exec] docker: 'rm 1234' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
     [exec] Result: 1
```

Can someone explain to me (a) where this different behavior comes from and (b) how to fix it (getting docker run from ant-target)?

Comment: Try <arg line="rm 1234" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a single argument through, your ant is the equivalent of saying

```
$ docker 'rm 1234'
```

Try

```
<target name="demo">
    <exec executable="docker">
        <arg value="rm" />
        <arg value="1234" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Sometimes ant drives my crazy. Thank you!